# How can I index specific rows to sum per year in r?

Tags: r

My data looks like this for 10 years:

```
df
   year week deaths
1  2001    0     36
2  2001    1     22
3  2001    2     32
4  2001    3     18
5  2001    4     35
6  2001    5     41
7  2001    6     42
8  2001    7     31
9  2001    8     46
```

I would like to sum the deaths in weeks zero and one per year. However, some years don’t have a week zero and therefore don’t need summing.

I’m having trouble indexing the weeks to sum! To then add to a for loop. Especially as they aren’t the same length and my years and weeks are in different columns and not as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep data for week 0-1 and then use `aggregate` to `sum` death value by year.

```
result <- aggregate(deaths~year, df, subset = week %in% 0:1, sum)
```

You can do this in `dplyr` and `data.table` as well.

```
#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(week %in% 0:1) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(deaths = sum(deaths))


#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[week %in% 0:1, .(deaths = sum(deaths)), year]
```